# I need to create a trigger I'm having trouble mariadb

Tags: triggers, mariadb

I need to create a trigger but I'm having trouble

```
CREATE TABLE `fotos` 
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `foto_patch` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `laudo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `check_list_foto_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
)

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `repetidos2` BEFORE INSERT ON `tb_cautelar_fotos` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.laudo_id =(
        SELECT
            laudo_id
        FROM
            `tb_cautelar_fotos`
        WHERE
            laudo_id = NEW.laudo_id
    ) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT
    = 'existe';
    END IF ;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So far everything works correctly, respects what I request, but I need this trigger to have a second option.

When laudo_id and check_list_foto_id exist, it displays the message exists.

Why can I have only one `chck_list_foto_id` for `laudo_id`?

I tried the following:

```
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.laudo_id AND new.check_list_foto_id ) = (
        SELECT
            laudo_id, check_list_foto_id
        FROM
            `tb_cautelar_fotos`
        WHERE
            laudo_id = NEW.laudo_id and check_list_foto_id = NEW.check_list_foto_id
    ) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT
        = 'existe';
    END IF ;
END
```

which results in this error on insert:

> #4078 - Illegal parameter data types boolean and row for operation '='

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: mysql ( Mariadb )

Comment: Not sure if related, but in both code examples, the `SELECT` statements are missing a `;` to terminate statement.

Comment: It looks like you are just enforcing a unique contraint in a table. Adding a `unique key` on `laudo_id` or making it a primary key seems like a better option.

Comment: hi yes it is working with unique key, however there is a condition that when the code is 999 I can allow several images, so the triggers I found a great option